# Orchard - Including Javascript files in partial views

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

In Orchard, how do I include a javascript file in my partial view that's loaded from an ajax call?

Here's what I've tried:

```
@{Script.Include("ownerInfo.js");}
```

Orchard completely ignores this if the view is hit from an ajax call

**Edit: The below works, although including scripts by hand is not ideal.  See Piedone's example below for a better alternative.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Modules/ModuleName/Scripts/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Script.Include works fine for me within a partial.  Are you missing the Web.config to allow you to get to static files in your script folder?

Comment: Script.Include is definitely the way to go, and works fine in shape templates. How are you including the partial view?

Comment: Sorry!  I forgot to include the fact that the view is loaded from an ajax call.  I suspect this is what is causing the issue, not the fact that it's a partial view.

Comment: Just to be clear, same problem, the script isn't loaded on an ajax call.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Could it be added by condition in the parent of the partial?

Comment: @Monkieboy thanks, good idea as a workaround for now.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is by design. If you look at Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceFilter (this is the filter adding those shapes to the layout that render static resources) it contains the following check:

```
// should only run on a full view rendering result
        if (!(filterContext.Result is ViewResult))
            return;
```

This prevents it from injecting the shapes into the layout if the action result is e.g. a PartialViewResult.

You could do the following:

- Insert the script "by hand"
- Include the script with Orchard and display the head and/or foot scripts' shape in your view:

  Display.HeadScripts()
  Display.FootScripts()

Comment: Thanks.  How would I insert the script by hand?  If I include the full path of the script (as shown in my question), Orchard throws an error about my js file not implementing IController.

Comment: The url /Modules/ModuleName/Scripts/script.js should work, if there is no application path configured for Orchard (like the default OrchardLocal). I'd go with displaying the resource shapes, because this way also the dependencies of your scripts will be included and your code will be portable.

Comment: You're right, looks like I had typed in my path incorrectly.  The url ./Modules/ModuleName/Scripts/script.js works as expected.  Note that you must include the period in the beginning of the path.